# How to deactivate image_transport plugins in ros2?

Tags: ros2, image-transport, compressed-image-transport

I am currently working with the image_transport package for publishing image topics. Among the available plugins, the latest image_transport_plugins package includes three formats: image_transport/compressed, image_transport/compressedDepth, and image_transport/theora.
I am interested in exclusively retaining the image_transport/compressed format and disabling the others.

While I am aware that uninstalling the corresponding plugins can disable the undesired output formats, I am wondering if it is possible to achieve this goal by modifying the launch file parameters. Is there a way to configure the launch file to specify which image transport plugins are active or deactivated?

Thank you for your assistance.

Best regards,

Comment: To be more specific, I use ROS2 Humble, and image_transport works just fine on it.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to identify what your mean by active and what your motivation is to make them "deactive"